# Vuetify data table - export to excel

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to export data from [vuetify data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) to excel. If user change sorting or filter data I want to export the data as I can see. Every operation is client-side, server only generates whole data source.

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :items-per-page="5"
></v-data-table>
...
created() {
  this.items = await this.$axios.$get('/api/get-items')
}
```

My idea is take json data and use e.g. [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) to generate excel file. But, there is only one prop (items), which is array before client-side operations (like sorting or filtering). Of cource, that I can take html code and parse data to json or edit api to accept sorting, filterig etc., but this is ugly way. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it client-side with one major restriction: you **will not be able to** use pagination on this table.

If it's OK for you, a special `@current-items` event should to the trick:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :items-per-page="-1"
  @current-items="onCurrentItemsChanged"
></v-data-table>
...
data () {
  return {
    currentItems: [],
    ...
  }
},
methods: {
  onCurrentItemsChanged(val) {
    this.currentItems = val;
  }
}
```

This emits the items every time the `internalCurrentItems` is changed.

But when you apply pagination, this event will return only **current page data**. Not all table elements are displayed at once (to improve performance, I guess).

You won't be able to implement this via HTML code parse either, because `v-data-table` produce `<tr>`s only for the elements of the current page.

So if you are not satisfied with this restriction, it'd be better to do it server-side.

You can test this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/gOoqzoJ).

Comment: Thanks for idea. Paging is important for me, so I'll have a look for other table component.